# Cannot rollback a Sequelize transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement OAuth2, but I'm stuck with *Sequelize* transactions.

Getting error:

```bash
Executing (9edf48f7-5823-4b4f-b444-faa4c1896831): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (9edf48f7-5823-4b4f-b444-faa4c1896831): COMMIT;
Unhandled rejection Error: commit has been called on this
    transaction(9edf48f7-5823-4b4f-b444-faa4c1896831), you can no longer
    use it. (The rejected query is attached as the 'sql' property of
    this error)
```

The following is the relevant JavaScript code:

```js
at.save({transaction: t}).then(() => {
                rt.save({transaction: t}).then(() => {
                    t.commit();
                    return done(false, accessToken, refreshToken, {
                        expires_at: expires,
                        scope: scope});
                }).error(function(
                    err) {
                    t.rollback();
                    return done(err);
                });
            }).error(function(err) {
                t.rollback();
                return done(err);
            });
```

I'm using Sequelize 4.x.x with Postgres

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you are working with Sequelize transactions using the auto-commit feature, you need to make sure that you return the promises from each of the queries.  It looks like you didn't return the promise from the nested queries, which means that your original promise resolves after the first query, which commits the transaction.  In order to wait for the entire chain of commits to finish, you must return the nested promises.

```
return sequelize.transaction(t => {
  return at.save({ transaction: t })
    .then(() => {
      return rt.save({ transaction: t })
        .then(() => {
          return t.commit() // Commit also returns a promise, you will want that to finish too
            .then(() => {
              return done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

In my example above you can completely omit the `t.commit()` call because Sequelize automatically commits a transaction if the promise chain resolves.  If you are not using the callback style for transaction then you should keep that there.  In my example I used the callback style.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Mine was using async and was missing an await as per this issue on the Sequelize github:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7525

Comment: For me a `forEach()` caused the transaction to automatically commit. Inside the forEach() I had a async. method. Can somebody explain this?